# Recovering a damaged PGD file

Tags: backup, data-recovery, file-recovery, pgp, virtual-disk

Recently, I got a disk crash and one partition of my HDD was wiped out. I used EaseusDataRecoveryWizard to search for some important files I had. There are 2 PGD files, virtual disks used by PGP software. Inside them, there are too many recent work I've done for the last 2 months.

Yes, I had backup, but it was a 2 months old one. During this time, I worked hard developing specific CAD drawings for some clients. My backup is too old and I need to recover that PGD files. My clients can wait. Time isn't a problem.

Easeus could find the files and could recover them. So far, so good.

Problem is that the files won't open anymore. At Easeus Help file it says that big files, like Mpeg videos, may not keep original integrity, due the file fragmentation, non contiguous space allocated, etc. So, I came here to hear some advices from you.

1. Why such things happens?
2. $MFT wasn't recovered? It didn't get the path, name and other datas
   for the file?
3. Where is the location for the pointer that points to the next not
   contiguous cluster of the file?
4. Why it was not recovered along with the other informations?

And the most important question:

**5. Is there a way to rebuild/fix that files?**

When I try to open the file, system warns: "PGP Disk Mount failed because: this file does not appear to be a valid PGP disk".

I think, even though Easeus has recovered the file with the exact size and time stamp, it may put some trash data inside the file, corrupting it.

How to fix that? Is it possible?

Comment: Your third question isn't an actual question that can be answered.

Comment: 6. How do I setup a proper backup strategy?

Comment: @Tetsujin - Why are you asking a question within a comment?

Comment: @Ramhound - that's what comments are for :P [it wasn't actually a question, it was a prompt to future behaviour]

Comment: A question towards the author is fine.  Asking how to setup a backup strategy doesn't seems out of place.  Confused how a question is not a question if it contains a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

> Why it was not recovered along with the other information?

Because the data wasn't complete.  The file was fragmented.  This means the file was located on multiple sectors, and likely on a sector that was bad, hence the reason your Master File Table was lost which was likely also on a bad sector.

> Where is the location for the pointer that points to the next not
>   contiguous cluster of the file?

You have not supplied enough information to answer this question.

> Why such things happens?

HDDs continuously determine if a sector is good or bad.  A file system also attempts to organize its files.  These two actions can interfere with one another if a sector goes bad before the complete data can be read and moved to another sector.  There are tools like `Spinrite` that MAY help in a case like this.  Its expensive and I am not actually doing a software recommendation specifically just saying there are tools that can help the HDD discover the missing data in a "bad" sector.  That only works before you write ANY data to the HDD, if you have, then the data is lost forever.

> Is there a way to rebuild/fix that files?

If the software does not support doing this then you are out of luck.  you cannot magically repair a file you don't understand nor know what the missing data should be.

Comment: Thank you, Ramhound, for your answers. In fact, HDD is healthy, there aren't bad sectors on it. Partition was deleted when I was installing Windows Seven on the same disk, but in other partition. I don't know what happened, because I took care to install on a empty partition. Nevertheless, Windows7 installation corrupted my data partition.

Comment: About my question #3, I want to know better how the $MFT stores the information of the next sector of the disk to keep going the file sequencies. I named it as a pointer. I mean, at the end of each segment, there should be some pointer to go the next direction. Where is it stored?
Also, is there some software to rebuild the $MFT? Because I guess the right strategy is not to recover files, as I'm doing now, but to try to reconstruct the original $MFTs and get the full disk folder tree back.